# Autoloading and Slim Framework won't work together with apache2 and php. Why?

Tags: php, apache2, slim

I successfully installed composer, Monolog and Slim Framework. However, when I insert this code...

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
date _default_timezone_set('America/New_york');

$log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('app.log',     Monolog\Logger::WARNING));
$log->addWarning('Foo');

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->run();
```

...into my .php file in my web project, but as I view the page in Mozilla all I get is an empty page. No app.log is created, no slim framework activity.

I have installed Composer globally, so the main files are located in     /usr/local/bin/composer. My current web project sits in     /var/www/html/my_project/

Comment: Do you have an error displayed? you have to look in the log apache2?

Comment: What slim version do you using?

Comment: This is what I found in the log:

[Fri Jan 22 14:02:31.335596 2016] [:error] [pid 1268] [client 127.0.0.1:40150] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '_default_timezone_set' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/my_project/index.php on line 4

I am using Slim version 3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

This :

```
date _default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
```

Should be this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_york');
```

Comment: I fixed that and now this shows up in the error.log